# NHibernate: how to handle entity-based validation using session-per-request pattern, without controllers knowing about ISession

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

What is the best way to do entity-based validation (each entity class has an `IsValid()` method that validates its internal members) in ASP.NET MVC, with a "session-per-request" model, **where the controller has zero (or limited) knowledge of the ISession**? Here's the pattern I'm using:

1. Get an entity by ID, using an `IFooRepository` that wraps the current NH session. This returns a connected entity instance.
2. Load the entity with potentially invalid data, coming from the form post.
3. Validate the entity by callings its `IsValid()` method.
4. If valid, call `IFooRepository.Save(entity)`, which delegates to `ISession.Save()`. Otherwise, display error message.

The session is currently opened when the request begins and **flushed when the request ends**. Since my entity is connected to a session, flushing the session attempts to save the changes *even if the object is invalid*.

What's the best way to keep validation logic in the entity class, limit controller knowledge of NH, and avoid saving invalid changes at the end of a request?

---

**Option 1: Explicitly evict on validation failure, implicitly flush**: if the validation fails, I could manually evict the invalid object in the action method. If successful, I do nothing and the session is automatically flushed.

*Con*: error prone and counter-intuitive (*"I didn't call .Save(), why are my invalid changes being saved anyways?"*)

**Option 2: Explicitly flush, do nothing by default**: By default I can dispose of the session on request end, only flushing if the controller indicates success. I'd probably create a `SaveChanges()` method in my base controller that sets a flag indicating success, and then query this flag when closing the session at request end.

*Pro*: More intuitive to troubleshoot if dev forgets this step [relative to option 1]

*Con*: I have to call `IRepository.Save(entity)`' **and** `SaveChanges()`.

**Option 3: Always work with disconnected objects:** I could modify my repositories to return disconnected/transient objects, and modify the `Repo.Save()` method to re-attach them.

*Pro*: Most intuitive, given that controllers don't know about NH.

*Con*: Does this defeat many of the benefits I'd get from NH?

Comment: http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/integration/ar.html#DataBindIssues

Comment: @Mauricio: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. I'm using a repository pattern, not Active Record, and I know the various techniques I could use to solve the problem (they are in the body of my question!). What I'm looking for is feedback regarding which of those options is most preferred, which might have unexpected "gotchas", and which might be considered anti-patterns.

Comment: @Seth: it doesn't matter for this case if it's ActiveRecord or not since AR is built on top of NHibernate. I just sent you that link because it *does* have possible gotchas for each option. Also I did not intend that single link to be a full answer, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: @Mauricio: I don't think its possible to _completely_ decouple my controllers from the session/UOW, at least not given my current application structure. I was looking at the TransactionScope options in the link you sent and I'm confused... the code shows a `tx.Rollback()` in the case of an exception, but AFAIK `TransactionScope` only has a `Complete()` method, not a rollback. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Seth: it's an ActiveRecord TransactionScope. With pure NH it would be an ITransaction.

Comment: About decoupling controllers-session, I see two options: delegate to a business layer (which would know about repositories which in turn would know about session), or use an ambient session, like ActiveRecord does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 without a doubt. It's not counter intuitive, it's how NH works. Objects retrieved using NH are persistent and changes will be saved when the session is flushed. Calling Evict makes the object transient which is exactly the behavior you want.

You don't mention it but another option might be to use Manual or Commit FlushMode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm trying to introduce NH onto a project that was started using a code-generated DAL to which other developers are accustomed. I want to keep the programming patterns as similar as possible, which means I am currently favoring "implicit rollback, explicit commit" solutions over "explicit rollback, implicit commit" ones. To someone unfamiliar with NH, Option 1 seems like the latter. I'm starting to agree, however, that  the _best_ solution is one that mirrors NH's design, rather than hides it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a validation service with an IsValid (or something similar) method which validates the object passed to it, if it fails it could publish a ValidationFailed event.  Then when your request finishes instead of calling the session's flush you could publish a RequestEnd event.  You could then have a handler that listens for both RequestEnd events and ValidationFailed events - if there is a ValidationFailed event then don't flush the session but if not then flush it.
Having said that I just do Option 2!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the entity-based validation is pretty much set in stone for this project, I'm trying to bring in NH with as minimal changes as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mauricio and Jamie have pointed out in their answers/comments, it's not easy (and probably not desirable) to do exactly what the question asks. NH returns persistent objects, so *exposing those objects to the controllers means the controllers are responsible for treating them as such*. I want to use lazy loading, so exposing detached instances won't work.

**Option 4: Introduce a new pattern that provides the desired semantics**

The point of this question is that I'm introducing NH+Repositories to an existing project using a hand-rolled, Active-Record-like DAL. I want code written NH to use patterns similar to the legacy code.

I created a new class called `UnitOfWork` that is a very thin wrapper over an `ITransaction` and that knows how to access the ambient session related to the current HttpRequest. This class is designed to be used in a *using* block, similar to `TransactionScope` which the team is familiar with:

```
using (var tx = new UnitOfWork()) {
    var entity = FooRepository.GetById(x);
    entity.Title = "Potentially Invalid Data";

    if (!entity.IsValid()) {
        tx.DiscardChanges();
        return View("ReloadTheCurrentView");
    }
    else {
        tx.Success();
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
```

The `tx.DiscardChanges()` is optional, this class has the same semantics as TransactionScope which means it will implicitly rollback if it is disposed before the success flag is set.

On a greenfield NH project I think it's preferable to use Option 1, as Jamie indicates in his answer. But I think Option 4 is a decent way to introduce NH on a legacy project that already uses similar patterns.